# If I add a font into my FTP for my website, when I am adding in my font, where do I put it in the FTP and how do I use the font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, web, ftp

If I add a font into my FTP for my website, when I am adding in my font, where do I put it in the FTP and how do I use the font with HTML or CSS ?

Comment: do you even try searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload the font where ever you want it, you just need to link to the right location. Please see exmaple below for font faces in CSS.

```
@font-face{
   font-family:'Your Font Name'; 
   src:url(http://www.example.com/fonts/YourFont.otf); 
}
```

Comment: So my font is called ( well the download of it is called ) Capture_it.ttf

If I wanted to have that in my #header then what would I do?

Comment: Put this at the top of your CSS file...`@font-face{
   font-family:'Capture'; 
   src:url(http://www.example.com/fonts/Capture_it.ttf); /*This depends where you have uploaded your font */
}`....
And then to set it in your header --->
`#header {font-family:'Capture'}`

Please don't forget to tick the answer if this does help.

Comment: Would the src:url be the website where I got it from which is http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Capture-it ?

Comment: No... the source would be where every you upload your font file too..... e.g. if you upload it to a folder called fonts in the root of your ftp, your src would be /fonts/Capture_it.ttf... it's simply just linking to the right location... like you would with a simple href link.

Comment: Please don't forget to click the tick when your questions have been answer, you have one outstanding at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995722/css-box-above-text-also-background-code-please too.

Answer (score 2):

I personally recommend use the [Font Squirrel Fontface generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) for that. You will get something like:

```
    /* @Fontface */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Yourfont';
        src: url('fonts/yourfont.eot');
        src: url('fonts/yourfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('fonts/yourfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('fonts/yourfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('fonts/yourfont.svg#Yourfont') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
    }
```

Using this way you will get a valid option to IE, Chrome, Opera, Firefox and Safari. Later you can use this font like a normal font, using

```
    div.heading { font-family: 'Yourfont', (othersifyouwant); }
```

Comment: I do use that, and I got it from here: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Capture-it

So how would I add that into my CSS and my #header?

Comment: You can use that folder scheme, so first of all create a new folder called 'fonts' or something in the folder of you css file. And place there your font/fonts files.

Then, add the @font-face code with your font configured, and set up

 
        #header { font-family: Yourfont; }